# python regex for time format, is this a good method?

Tags: python, regex

I saw this from a textbook to match the time format by regex:

```
t = '19:05:30'
m = re.match(r'^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9])\:(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9]|5[0-9]|[0-9])\:(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9]|5[0-9]|[0-9])$', t)
#            limited to 0X or 1X or 2X or x
#                                              limited to 1X, 2X, 3X, 4X, 5X or X
#                                                                                                  same as minutes
print(m.groups())
# >>> ('19', '05', '30')
```

Obviously it worked, but it seems to be quite redundant, can I use:

```
m = re.match(r'^(2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]|[0-9])\:([0-5][0-9])\:([0-5][0-9])$', t)
print(m.groups())
# >>> ('19', '05', '30')
```

I am quite new at regex, and I am not sure if I can easily write something better than a textbook, but I can't find anything wrong with it.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not use `datetime`?

Comment: Certainly ``r'[0-2]?\d(\:[0-5]?\d){2}'`` should be more concise, but you should use a datetime parser

Comment: @coldspeed wow, that looks nice, but is mine wrong in any way?

Comment: I can, I am just learning how to use `re` for now...

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 Probably not but you did mention it was redundant, which it is... so there's that.

Comment: OTOH, it might make more sense over regex to `h, m, s = map(int, '19:05:30'.split(':'))` and then individually check whether `h`, `m`, and `s` are within the expected ranges.

Comment: @coldspeed   I think yours has a flaw, that I can type '29:30:30", and it will match, which is wrong,

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out... this looks a bit more clunky: `r'((?:[01]?\d)|(?:2[0-3]))(\:[0-5]?\d){2}'`

Comment: @coldspeed  well, at least I can read one with no problem now, that's something.

Comment: @coldspeed You are over-complicating things: `r'([01]?+d|2[0-3])\:([0-5]\d)\:([0-5]\d)'` will do. You do need to duplicate the second group to catch minutes and seconds separately, or you will not have access to both groups after your match.

Comment: I should not try to write a regex directly in a comment, due to the risk of error, but let my try to fix it (by yet again writing in a comment): `r'([01]\d|2[0-3])\:([0-5]\d)\:([0-5]\d)'` Hopefully this is more correct.

Comment: @JohanL creative. I like it. I wonder if you regex should include a leading 0 as option though